# Removing /protecting the id in the url from tampering

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-authorization, penetration-testing, web-application-security

I'm working on solving some application vulnerabilities. I have an edit page with a url `http://localhost:12997/Manning_HQ/Edit/1274` the problem was users were able to change the the id and be able to access other requests that were not supposed to access.

I searched the `URLEncoding` but found that it only ensures that all browsers will correctly transmit text in URL strings. My question is there a way to prevent this?

My edit function:

```
// GET: Manning_HQ/Edit/5
        [CustomAuthorize(Roles = AccessRoleHelper.Add_Manning_Plan_HQ)]
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            var test1 = (from c in db.TBL_Manning_HQ
                         join e in db.TBL_User_Dep_Access
                         on c.Inserted_By equals e.UserID
                         join t in db.TBL_Department
                         on c.Department_ID equals t.Department_ID
                         join p in db.TBL_Location
                         on c.Location_ID equals p.Location_ID
                         join n in db.TBL_Titles_HQ
                        on c.TitleHQ_ID equals n.TitleHQ_ID

                         where (e.Dep_ID == c.Department_ID)
                         where c.Manning_HQ_ID == id
                         select new Manning_HQ_VM
                         {
                             Manning_HQ_ID = c.Manning_HQ_ID,

                         }).ToList();
          
            TBL_Manning_HQ tBL_Manning_HQ = db.TBL_Manning_HQ.Find(id);
            int userid = Convert.ToInt32(Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"].ToString().Split('\\')[1].ToString().Remove(0, 2));

            if (tBL_Manning_HQ == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            var departments = (from d in db.TBL_Department
                               join ud in db.TBL_User_Dep_Access
                               on d.Department_ID equals ud.Dep_ID
                               join m in db.TBL_Manning_HQ
                               on d.Department_ID equals m.Department_ID
                               where ud.UserID == userid && ud.IsActive == true
                               where m.Manning_HQ_ID == id
                               select new KeyValuePairsViewModel
                               {
                                   Id = d.Department_ID,
                                   Value = d.Department_Name
                               }).ToList();

            ViewBag.Department_ID = new SelectList(departments, "Id", "Value");
            ViewBag.Location_ID = new SelectList(db.TBL_Location, "Location_ID", "Location_Name", tBL_Manning_HQ.Location_ID);
            ViewBag.TitleHQ_ID = new SelectList(db.TBL_Titles_HQ, "TitleHQ_ID", "Title_Name", tBL_Manning_HQ.TitleHQ_ID);


            if (test1.Count != 0)
            {

                return View(tBL_Manning_HQ);

            }
            else
            {
                return View();

            }
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [CustomAuthorize(Roles = AccessRoleHelper.Add_Manning_Plan_HQ)]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(TBL_Manning_HQ _HQ)
        {
            
            var chk_ID = db.TBL_Manning_HQ.Any(x => x.Manning_HQ_ID == _HQ.Manning_HQ_ID);
            var Chk_Dep = db.TBL_Manning_HQ.Where(x=>x.Manning_HQ_ID == _HQ.Manning_HQ_ID).Any(x => x.Department_ID == _HQ.Department_ID);

            if (chk_ID && Chk_Dep)
            {
                _HQ.Update_By = Convert.ToInt32(Request.ServerVariables["LOGON_USER"].ToString().Split('\\')[1].ToString().Remove(0, 2));
                _HQ.Update_In = DateTime.Now;

                db.SaveChanges();

                TempData["success"] = "Data updated successfully !";
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Custom Authorize:

```
 public class CustomAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        Staff_RequisitionEntities_1 db = new Staff_RequisitionEntities_1();

        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
            }

            if (filterContext.HttpContext.User == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext.HttpContext.User");
            }

            string username = filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name.ClientName();
            int xceedId = Convert.ToInt32(username.Substring(2));
           
            var user = db.TBL_UserPermissions.FirstOrDefault(us => us.UserID== xceedId && us.IsActive == true);

            {
                filterContext.HttpContext.User = new CustomPrincipal((WindowsIdentity)filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity,user, true , Convert.ToString(xceedId));
                base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

            }
        }
    }
```

Access role helper:

```
 public class AccessRoleHelper
    {
        public const string Manning_Plan = "Add Manning Plan";    
        public const string View_Manning_Plan = "View Manning Plan";    
        public const string Add_New_Request = "Add New Request";    
        public const string View_Requestes = "View Requestes";    
        public const string Add_Fulfillment_Rate = "Add Fulfillment Rate";    
        public const string View_Fulfillment_Rate = "View Fulfillment Rate";
        public const string Add_Manning_Plan_HQ = "Add Manning Plan HQ";
        public const string View_Manning_Plan_HQ = "View Manning Plan HQ";
        public const string View_Manning_Plan_HQ_CombCEO = "View Manning Plan HQ Manager"; 
        public const string View_Manning_Plan_CEO = "View Manning Plan CEO";
        public const string Add_Issue_staff_requisition = "Add Issue staff requisition"; 
        public const string Training_Action = "Training Action";
        public const string Admin = "Admin";
        public const string Rec_Action = "Recruitment Actions";
    }
```

Custom principal:

```
public CustomPrincipal(WindowsIdentity source, TBL_UserPermissions baseUser ,bool inDb, string ID) :
            base(source)
        {
            
            UserPermission = baseUser;

           
            HttpContext.Current.Session["USERID"] = ID;
        }

        public override bool IsInRole(string role)
        {
           
            bool hasPermission = false;
            if (UserPermission != null && (UserPermission.UserID != null))
            {
               
                hasPermission = db.TBL_UserPermissions.Any(up => up.TBL_Permissions.PermissionName == role && up.IsActive == true && up.UserID == UserPermission.UserID);
            }
         
         return (base.IsInRole(role) || (hasPermission));
        }

        public TBL_UserPermissions UserPermission { get; protected set; }
```

Comment: Never trust user input, period! You need to verify that they have access to the page on the server side in the your HttpPost method. Redirect them to a different page if they don't have access.

Comment: You already have an action filter; `[CustomAuthorize(Roles = AccessRoleHelper.Add_Manning_Plan_HQ)]`. Is Mannig_HQ owned by individual users or individual entities that isn't handled by that action filter?

Comment: Hi @JerdineSabio, I guess by individual users .I'm going to edit the post to share the code of it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some sort of verification, one easy way to do is is to add another number at the end for verification and discard it when you try to acces the page.

For example you and use the sum of digits of the number:

For URL
`http://localhost:12997/Manning_HQ/Edit/1274`

Sum = 1+2+7+4 =>14 -> 1+4 => **5**

The new url will be
`http://localhost:12997/Manning_HQ/Edit/12745`

Comment: Check digits like this are generally useful for situations where you are helping prevent errors when users are entering a numeric sequence, not a protection mechanism. This isn't a substitute for validating that the current user has access to the row and acting on a detected tamper.

Answer (score 0):

Server-side, controller/API code can never trust data coming from the client. For a controller method you will have an authenticated user associated with the session. For every request you should assert that the provided ID can be modified by the session user. API methods will include authentication tokens to assert and identify the User in order to determine if they are accessing appropriate records.

If you detect that an ID is coming in that the current user does not have access to, it is an immediate event log notification to administrators about the violation (User ID, record ID, date/time, IP Address, etc.) and terminating the user's session. (Kick to login)  The system should track these violations against users and repeated attempts should lock the user's account in the event that their account has been compromised. (Typically it's just a curious bumpkin wondering if something is open/possible)

The same goes for any data coming back with the update request. Everything needs to be validated and only the fields that you allow to be updated should be persisted. This is the #1 reason I advise that you never pass EF entities between client and server. The payload of a request can be tampered with, so code that does an Attach + Modified or Update approach is vulnerable to data tampering.

Comment: There is a custom authorise for user ID . I edited the post to add the code for it .But i guess it doesn't do the trick .should i add if else and if the user not authorised i transfer them to an error page ?

Comment: If a user accesses something they aren't authorized I would recommend terminating the session and notifying admins. This kicks the user out to the Authentication/Login page.  Whether RowIDs are passed by URL or data there is no way to actively prevent tampering. You can try to obfuscate it, but at the end of the day if tampering is detected it should treat the session as compromised and end it.